# What version of Eclipse is IBM IID 8.5 Based on

Tags: perforce, ibm-bpm

I am wanting to install the Perforce p4 plugin in IBM IID 8.5, and would like to know where to find the Eclipse Version it runs on. I have tried to install other plugins, and had to re-install IID since they were incompatible

I've looked in About, welcome, and IBM Developer forums but the topic is not addressed

Answer (score 0):

Try Help-> About Eclipse, then click through the eclipse looking icons.   Look for Feature Name "Eclipse Platform".